# PowerBI - Cannot find the new calculated table

Tags: powerbi, relation, powerbi-desktop

I am new to PowerBi and I am trying to work on some tables (in this example I am working with data on the corona virus).

I built a new table and named it "table1". Now I want to reach out to this table but Power BI cannot find the related table. You can see in the screenshot, how PowerBi is not considering the table.
the two tables are connected by a 1_to_many relation (table1 has every country once; the current table has every country often).

Thanks in advance for your help!

[image: PowerBi not responding to the table]

Best regards

Comment: Ist `table1` dependent on that table? If so, you might have circular reference issues.

Comment: Well, there is a meaure I created in that table ("time_series..."). That measure is used in the table1. Would that be a problem? I cannot use the table1 at all. Also not in my report...